# How can I tell Unity to use specific frames for animation?

Tags: unity, animation, blender, import

So I have made a set of animations in a one file in **Blender.** For example, frame 0-20 idle animation, 30-60 walking animation, 70-120 jumping animation.

How can I tell the program to separate the animations by selecting those frames, cutting them or something and this way I could have a set of animations without needing to save .blend files separately with the animations?

Comment: Well, you *really* should separate those into separate animations in Blender so you can use them as separate animations in Unity. It will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: @Philipp Oh so I should make separate .blend files with the appropriate animations? There would be around 7 of them, can Unity import several files for animation with no problems?

Comment: No, Blender allows you to define several animations for the same model in the same  file. When you then import that one Blender file, Unity will import those animations as separate animation clips which you can then use as separate animation states in your Unity Animation Controller. If you need help with Blender, you might want to try https://blender.stackexchange.com.